# Android emulator doesn't start

Tags: 13.10, android, emulation

My android emulator was working with ubuntu 13.10 x64 till I reinstalled it.
I have downloaded java jdk and jre, the newest version of the Android Development Tools for linux x64, libstdc++6:i386 and lib32z1.
When I now run my emulator from Eclipse, I get a black emulator window with android not loading. I have also tried to run the emulator on command line and this error is showing up:

```
emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library: lib64OpenglRender.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
```

I am confused because nothing else is installed on my ubuntu machine despite updates!

Comment: which acceleration?

Comment: AVD manager (tools > Manage AVD's) > select the device > Edit > Uncheck: Emulation option - Use Host GPU

Comment: It is already disabled.

Comment: Google `lib64OpenglRender.so: cannot open` if you want a quick answer.

Comment: Works only with Use Host GPU on!?

Comment: disabling GPU acceleration might work. Have you tried clearing the cache? Also try launching as administration right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really strange:
In the comments someone advised me to switch off acceleration through GPU. I had already switched it off but never tried to switch it on. Then I noticed that with the last install of Ubuntu I have always switched it on....

So when I run my emulator on commandline it is still the same error but in eclipse not!